# Record Not Found rails 5 ActiveRecord Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am trying to use a vanity URL that uses the SecureRandom issued ident to a culvert, and then display that culvert via the show page.

This is a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

This is a screenshot of the browser url:
[image]

> **My Culvert Controller is:**

I have tried Both:

```
@culvert = Culvert.find_by_culvert_ident(params[:id])
  AND
@culvert = Culvert.find_by_id(params[:culvert_ident])
```

In my culvert controller show action, both yield the same result (screenshot)

```
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_culvert
      @culvert = Culvert.find_by_culvert_ident(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def culvert_params
      params.require(:culvert).permit(:culvert_ident, :latitude, :longitude, :address, :user_id)
    end
```

This is my Culvert Model ident generator and vanity url methods:

```
  before_create :generate_culvert_ident

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :user

  # Model Validations
  validates_uniqueness_of :culvert_ident

  # Ident Generator
  def generate_culvert_ident
    begin
      self.culvert_ident = SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase
      other_culvert = Culvert.find_by(culvert_ident: self.culvert_ident)
    end while other_culvert
  end

  # Url Direction
  def to_param
    culvert_ident
  end
```

So my goal is to create the culvert, auto assign a unique identifier, save it and display the culvert using the custom identifier as opposed to the standard 1,2,3,4 id's

this works in another web app i have used, is setup exactly the same but i am getting this error here and cant figure out why. Please let me knwo if you require further info!

**

> EDIT # 1 - Adds Screenshot of Console output

**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the record exist with that `id`?

Comment: yes when i search it in console it pulls the record and shows the ident is saved as well as the standard id - actually it shows up as nil -- see above screenshot ill update it now

Comment: What does `Culvert.where('culvert_ident = ?', 'BF83D4').first` give?

Comment: It dosnt return nil in console ill add the console output above - it appears to work with your query it formatted wonkey its the little screenshot above the original

Comment: I believe `find_by_column_name` doesn't work anymore. I believe the syntax has changed in RoR 4 - try with `find_by(:culvert_ident: 'BF83D4')`. However, with `where` and `first` you can get the same result.

Comment: Update - [here's the reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was that I removed the culverts controller

```
before_action :set_culvert
```

as soon as I re-added the set_user action the issue was resolved.

thanks for your assistance!